# Passing in strings to functions using rlang::sym and exclamation marks

Tags: r, string, function

I have a function where I attempt to get a one-hot encoding of a column. My issue appears to be some issue with how R interprets the string value of the column when it is passed in from a function:

```
function_notworking = function(data, col){

result = model.matrix(~col -1, data=data)
return(result)
}
 # doesnt work
function_notworking(data=iris, col='Species')
```

However, if I do:

```
model.matrix(~Species -1, data = iris) it does work just fine.
```

Further I have tried to look into this adding rlang::sym() and !! in front of 'col' but that doesn't seem to work either.

```
function_notworking = function(data, col){
    col = rlang::sym(col) # 
    result = model.matrix(~col -1, data=data)
    #or result = model.matrix(~!!col -1, data=data)
    return(result)
    }
```

Looking to understand how to pass in column names like this to a function and not receive an issue.

If I use expr() around the code it seems that the !!rlang::sym(col) code does its job but I'm stuck.

Comment: The issue is with not using `paste`  i.e. `paste0("~", col, -1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
makeMM <- function(data, col) model.matrix(~ . - 1, data[col])

# test
makeMM(iris, "Species")
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to do a `paste`

```
function_working = function(data, col){

    model.matrix(as.formula(paste0("~ ", col,  -1)), data=data)
    # or create the formula with glue
    # model.matrix(formula(glue::glue("~{col} -1")), data = data) 

 }

function_working(data=iris, col="Species")
```